# Dynamically sizing a container view based on the view controller inside it in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Within my application, I have a `UIScrollView` with a `containerView` inside it. Based on buttons pressed by the user, I swap a different `UIViewController` into the `containerView`.

The problem is, I need to figure out the `height` of this new `UIViewController` so that I can adjust the size of the `containerView`'s `height` constraint.

What I am currently doing is

```
@IBOutlet weak var content: UIView!
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
if let vc = getViewController(sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.transition(from: self.currentViewController!,
                        to: vc,
                        duration: 0.5,
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve,
                        animations: {
                            self.currentViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
                            vc.view.frame = self.content.bounds
                            self.content.addSubview(vc.view)
                        },
                        completion: { finished in                   
         self.currentViewController!.removeFromParentViewController()
                            self.currentViewController = vc
                        })

    }
}
```

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: @SAHM It's been a while, but I think this method solved it for me: 

https://gist.github.com/BrandonSlaght/000a8735220384c6d398cdd46bf3f1f3

remember to call 

`self.addedViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and 
`self.addChildViewController(addedViewController)`

before using the addSubview method

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to adjust the `contentSize` property on a scrollview, why not setting `content.contentSize = vc.view.frame.size` ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me: there is no property `contentSize` for a UIView

Comment: the scrollview has a contentSize. 
`//assuming vc.view has its frame set to {{0,0},{goodWidth,goodHeight}}`
then `content.bounds = vc.view.bounds` then `scrollView.contentSize = content.frame`

Answer (score 0):

You need a subview property  and add it to the controller in the container that all your content goes in that is pinned to the top of the view and the sides in the viewcontroller with No bottom constraint. You need to make sure it is laid out with all the content and get the height of that view and update your height constraint on the viewcontroller holding this container with preferably a delegate method. If any of the views this content view holds does not have an intrinsic size assign one in Autolayout and it will need to stay the same.